# Adding a toggle function to PeriodicTimer in .Net 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, timer

What is the best way to implement a toggle (ON/OFF) for the `PeriodicTimer`? I will like to make a user interface where the toggle can be switched. Is it best to store toggle status in a DB or in memory? My environment is `.NET6 WebApi`, with an `Angular` Frontend.

```
services.AddHostedService<RepeatingListCheck>();
```

```
namespace Service
{
    public class RepeatingListCheck : BackgroundService
    {

        private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer = new(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25));
        public ILogger<RepeatingListCheck> Logger { get; }

        public RepeatingListCheck(ILogger<RepeatingListCheck> logger)
        {
            this.Logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken) && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await CheckList();
            }
        }


        public static async Task CheckList()
        {

            int[] list = { AC16, FE17, VQ18 };

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var PaymentOrder = new PaymentRequestOrder()
                {
                    //do something
                };

                var SendJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SendJson );
                HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
                var Response = await http.PostAsync("", httpContent);
               // more code

            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a DB as a system property. Web APIs are stateless, and the web server could go down, restart, add another server instance to a pool, etc. and may not have access to that toggle value. Putting it in some storage mechanism like a DB, or key/value pairs in a shared storage container (like on Azure) would persist the toggle value on a more permanent basis.